# How would I test this method?

Tags: testing, go, automated-tests

Essentially I've begun to work on a wrapper for the Riot Games API and I'm struggling with how to test it. I've got the repository plugged into Travis so on push it runs `go test` but I'm not sure how to go about testing it since the API_KEY required for the requests changes daily and I can't auto-regenerate it, i'd have to manually add it every day if I tested the endpoints directly.

So I was wondering if it was possible to mock the responses, but in that case I'm guessing I'd need to refactor my code?

So i've made a struct to represent their SummonerDTO

```
type Summoner struct {
    ID            int64  `json:"id"`
    AccountID     int64  `json:"accountId"`
    ProfileIconID int    `json:"profileIconId"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
    Level         int    `json:"summonerLevel"`
    RevisionDate  int64  `json:"revisionDate"`
}
```

That struct has a method:

```
func (s Summoner) ByName(name string, region string) (summoner *Summoner, err error) {
    endpoint := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/%s/summoners/by-name/%s", REGIONS[region], VERSION, name)

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", endpoint, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to create new client for request: %v", err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("X-Riot-Token", API_KEY)

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to complete request to endpoint: %v", err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("request to api failed with: %v", resp.Status)
    }

    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to read response body: %v", err)
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(respBody), &summoner); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to unmarshal response body to summoner struct: %v", err)
    }

    return summoner, nil
}
```

Is it a case that the struct method doesn't have a single responsibility, in a sense it's building the endpoint, firing off the request and parsing the response. Do I need to refactor it in order to make it testable, and in which case what's the best approach for that? Should I make a Request and Response struct and then test those?

To clarify the API Keys used are rate limited and need to be regenerated daily, Riot Games do not allow you to use a crawler to auto-regenerate your keys. I'm using Travis for continuous integration so I'm wondering if there's a way to mock the request/response.

Potentially my approach is wrong, still learning.

Hopefully that all makes some form of sense, happy to clarify if not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing unit tests consists of:

- Providing known state for all of your inputs.
- Testing that, given all meaning combinations of those inputs, you receive the expected outputs.

So you need to first identify your inputs:

- `s Summoner`
- `name string`
- `region string`

Plus any "hidden" inputs, by way of globals:

- `client := &http.Client{}`

And your outputs are:

- `summoner *Summoner`
- `err error`

(There can also be "hidden" outputs, if you write files, or change global variables, but you don't appear to do that here).

Now the first three inputs are easy to create from scratch for your tests:  Just provide an empty `Summoner{}` (since you don't read or set that at all in your function, there's no need to set it other than to an empty value).  `name` and `region` can simply be set to strings.

The only part remaining is your `http.Client`.  At minimum, you should probably pass that in as an argument. Not only does this give you control over your tests, but it allows you to use easily use different client in production in the future.

But to ease testing, you might consider actually passing in a client-like interface, which you can easily mock. The only method you call on `client` is `Do`, so you could easily create a `Doer` interface:

```
type doer interface {
    Do(req *Request) (*Response, error)
}
```

Then change your function signature to take that as one argument:

```
func (s Summoner) ByName(client doer, name string, region string) (summoner *Summoner, err error) {
```

Now, in your test you can create a custom type that fulfills the `doer` interface, and responds with any `http.Response` you like, without needing to use a server in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, looks like a thorough and thought out process to me. Will give it a bit of time for anyone else to chime in before I accept the answer.